# JSF 2, CDI 1.1, SpringSecurity 4: Custom login form não redireciona para página

Tags: java, jsf, spring, spring-security

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com JSF 2, SpringSecutiry 4 e CDI 1.1.

Fiz toda a implementação do SpringSecurity com JSF e aparentemente tudo funcionou normalmente, porém ao fazer o form de login customizado, o mesmo redireciona para links de arquivos no Head do HTML. Se eu uso o form login do spring tudo funciona corretamente.

Seguem os códigos:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {
    "br.com.projectus.acompobra.negocio",
    "br.com.projectus.acompobra.dao"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/faces/login.xhtml?logout")
                .permitAll().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/faces/login.xhtml")
                .failureUrl("/faces/login.xhtml?erro").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/faces/login.xhtml");
    }

}
```

HTML Page:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="login.css"/>
        <title>Projectus - SGO</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../resources/images/logo_prj.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param.erro != null}">  
            <p>Dados inválidos.</p>
        </h:panelGroup> 
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param.logout != null}">  
            <p>Logout efetuado com sucesso.</p>  
        </h:panelGroup>

        <div id="header-wrapperLogin">
            <div id="headerLogin">
                <div id="logoLogin">

                    <h:form id="form" prependId="false">  
                        <h2>Seja bem vindo. Entre com os dados abaixo para realizar o login.</h2> 
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Usuário" />  
                            <h:inputText id="username" />   
                            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Senha" />  
                            <h:inputSecret id="password"  />  
                        </h:panelGrid>  
                        <p:commandButton value="Enviar" /> 
                    </h:form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A ordem da configuração do método configure(HttpSecurity http) é importante, caso colocar/setar as configurações tudo ordem aleatório, pode ocorrer problemas para o Spring Security reconhecer.

Mesmo caso essa não seja a situação nesse cenário, é possivel redirecionar manualmente, criando um Handler e setando ele junto as configurações do Spring Security `.successHandler(new AuthSuccessHandler())`

Ex:

```
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(isAdmin()) {
        response.sendRedirect("admin");
    }
    response.sendRedirect("usuario"); 
  }
}
```